# RAILS GENERATE MIGRATION CreateContacts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations, c9.io

I am using **c9 IDE**.

The command I entered in the terminal: `bundle exec rails generate migration CreateContacts`.

I get a message: `error: could not find 'rails'`.

This is the command in Nitrous, is there a different command in cloud9?

Is there a step-by-step procedure to manually create the rails migration `CreateContacts` in the File Directory in cloud9? What code is entered into the newly created files. I notice in the Rails Guide a a file is generated e.g. number `(YYYYMMDDHHMMSS)_create_contacts.rb`, if this file is manually created will this number e.g. `(20160928130510)_create_contacts.rb` - be correct and what code is entered into the file?

I'm pretty stuck here and need some expert guidance on this one please.

Comment: I think Cloud9 works the same way one should expect it from a normal development environment. Are you sure you are typing this command inside the rails application root path ?

Answer (score 1):

I use cloud9 IDE as well and when i want to create a migration file i simply do rails generate migration . (I dont include bundle exec in the command)

The file generated in the migration folder will be created in the YYYYMMDDHHMMSS format.

Comment: Thanks Imran, you're a star, I entered rails generate migration CreateContacts in the Terminal, and the migration file was generated. Much appreciated my friend!

Comment: Imran your solution worked perfectly and it generated the migration file I needed. I am faced with another problem. My Submit button do not submit and I get no error message. The question was posted, it includes my code in the rails application. Your expert advice needed, I am stuck at this juncture.